# 90s kids or 90's kids or 90s' kids or '90s kids

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, numbers, apostrophe, time

I have been checking on which of these is grammatically correct. Should we use "90s kids" or "90's kids" or "90s' kids" or "'90s kids"? I checked on many forums and platforms like Reddit, Oxford, and many others. People discuss 90s kids and 90's kids and '90s kids, but no one talks about 90s' kids which I think is most appropriate as we use s' for plurals. Here is my research:

Oxford Dictionaries: [How To Use An Apostrophe (’)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe).

Reddit: [90s vs 90's. Which one is correct?](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/3ir72f/90s_vs_90s_which_one_is_correct/) (August 2015).

Some even say that it should be written '90s as we are omitting 19 from 1990. So what do you all think?

Comment: I forgot to mention that while we are writing 90s' kids (or whatever), we need to keep in mind that here we are talking about possession.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicative, and slightly more than one month older: [Apostrophe Use In Abbreviated Decade Which Is Also A Possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484037/apostrophe-use-in-abbreviated-decade-which-is-also-a-possessive).

Comment: There is precious little agreement as to the applicable "standards" here.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the first (leading) apostrophe is for omission (of "19" in "1990"),

1990 → **'90** omission

90 → **90s**  plural → **90s'**  possessive, plural

→ **'90s'**

and the second (trailing) apostrophe is for plural possession, ending up in "**'90s' (kids)**."

But oh, bother! I'd think "**90s kids**" eminently serves the purpose without ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the number out, it would be **Nineties' kids**, so **90s'** would be the appropriate numerical format.

Having said that, **the 90s"** is a contraction for **the 1990s**, so it seems to me that **'90s'** would be technically correct – although it really doesn't look good, so I'd stick with **90s'**.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am wondering about. The correct one should be '90s', but that will look really weird.

Comment: In writing out, *the Nineties* has a distinct meaning, so doesn't need a leading apostrophe. That doesn't compare with using figures.

Comment: @Kris that's precisely what I was saying :)

Comment: Not convinced by "Nineties' kids" - you would say "Jazz Age kids" or "Colonial era housing" or "2 o'clock train" without a possessive (although you might say "Wednesday's child").