# Since the ___, the company has doubled in size

Tags: grammar

Since the ___, the company has doubled in size.

a. 1990's

b. 1990s

c. 1990s'

d. 1990ies

After searching on Google, I think the answer is b. However, when I submit the final answer, it says that my answer is incorrect. I have been reading a lot of articles and I found that the authors are also using 1990s, 1970s, etc. Anyone can correct my understanding when mentioning the year? Thank you.

Comment: (b) looks good.  (a) looks ok to me too - it's possible that (a) was at some point the preferred answer, but one routinely sees (b).  (c) and (d) are, to quote Brother Maynard, right out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an apostrophe with a decade (e.g. 1920’s) generally considered “incorrect”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13631/is-an-apostrophe-with-a-decade-e-g-1920-s-generally-considered-incorrect)

Comment: See also [90s kids or 90's kids or 90s' kids or '90s kids](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/490368/90s-kids-or-90s-kids-or-90s-kids-or-90s-kids) and [What is the correct way to pluralize an acronym / initialism?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pluralize-an-acronym-initialism), among others.

Comment: ...also see [***this NGram***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since+the+90s%2Csince+the+90%27s&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), showing that apostrophe-less ***since the 90s*** is three times as popular as the "grocers' apostrophe" version ***since the 90's***.

Answer (score 1):

1990s is the way to go. There's no possession here. The only time when it's appropriate to use an apostrophe with digits is if the text would be confusing. (E.g. "1's and 0's" is clearer than "1s and 0s".)